# React component taking some random values

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment

These are my components.
This is quicksort.js =>

```
import React from "react";
import "../CSS/Quicksort.css";
import Bar from "./Bar";

export default function Quicksort() {
  var arr = new Array(50);
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(400));
  }

  console.log(arr);
  arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return  a-b;
  });
  console.log(arr);
  const mp = arr.map((num, idx) => {
    return <Bar key={idx} height={num} />;
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div className="layout">{mp}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is Bar.js =>

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import React from 'react'
import '../CSS/Bar.css';

export default function Bar({height}) {
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
        bar:{
            fontSize:10,
            height:height,
            width:20,
            backgroundColor:"red",
            color:"white"
        }
    });
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.bar} >
                {height}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

and this is the picture of the output

[image]

Look at the element inspected the 4th element in the array and the rendered element.
In the image it is that the 4th element I passed from the randomly generated array which is 21 but the height of the element rendered is 23.
Please help me with this. Thank you :)

Comment: Please clarify, ***in your question*** what the issue is. It's completely unclear from the image what you want us to look at.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood your question completely, but you are using  a function to generate random numbers and passing those numbers to your array. So, whatever random number you are passing, Your "Bar" component is showing it correctly. So, what is the issue here? Can you give more description?

Comment: if your issue is that the red bars are two pixels more than calculated height (23 vs 21), to me it looks like it adds border of 1 px of the same colour somehow, are there 2 px extra in all bars?

Comment: In the image it is that the 4th element I passed from the randomly generated array which is 21 but the height of the element rendered is 23.

Comment: @krankuba I checked it. If it is that you are saying it should be consistent for all but it is not when I reloaded the page my array has first element as 8 and the rendered element had the height of 7

Comment: Right, I *had* noticed the height discrepancy as well, and figured *some* border or similar was added. Notice though that the width is half what you specify it to be, so it's all still a bit unclear. Have you inspected the computed styles to see what is setting width/height/etc? Can you try creating a ***running*** codesandbox that we may live debug in?

Comment: @DrewReese If I share my repo of the project , will it be helpful to you? htttps://github.com/manishsencha here in the repo manishsencha.gihub.io you can find them in src/components.

Comment: I cloned, installed, and ran your code, the quicksort bars, for me, are all 20px wide and the height matches that of the number label. In your screenshot I don't see the labels. If you can create a running demo that reproduces that issue then we can inspect/debug on it.

Comment: @DrewReese I was debugging a while ago and I did that while trying to debug but the problem is same. they are matching the height, I agree but If you  inspect and open the console you will see the array and the element heights does not match in the array.

Comment: @krankuba I shared my repo in the above comments If you could help me I would be very thankful.

Comment: I just did took a look and the answer of @DrewReese just poped up. Please, read it carefully and apply the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You are creating and sorting arrays in the component body of a functional component, which is a side-effect and anti-pattern in React.

```
export default function Quicksort() {
  var arr = new Array(50); // <-- side-effect
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(400)); // <-- side-effect
  }

  console.log(arr); // <-- side-effect
  arr.sort(function (a, b) { // <-- side-effect
    return a - b;
  });
  console.log(arr); // <-- side-effect

  const mp = arr.map((num, idx) => {
    return <Bar key={idx} height={num} />;
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div className="layout">{mp}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

The ***entire*** body of a functional component ***IS*** the render function and your side-effects are being called during the "render phase" and messing with the output/returned UI in the "commit phase" when the ReactDOM is pushed to the browser DOM.

## Solution

Create the array data *outside* the component, and thus outside the React component lifecycle, or put it in state so it is bound to the component lifecycle. Use an `useEffect` hook to correctly log the array when the component renders to the DOM.

```
export default function Quicksort() {
  const [arr] = React.useState(
    [...Array(50)]
      .map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(400)))
      .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(arr);
  }, [arr]);

  const mp = arr.map((num, idx) => {
    return <Bar key={idx} height={num} />;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div className="layout">{mp}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-component-taking-some-random-values]